# When I place a straw in carbontated drink and blow, more gas bubbles rise to the surface?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution

When I place a straw in carbontated drink and blow (making bubbling noises), more gas bubbles rise to the surface. The gas bubbles which rise to the surface are from the carbon dioxide gas dissolved in the drink, I'm not talking about the air bubbles I made with the straw?

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your "experimental" set up? Maybe while blowing your breath into the drink, you also stir it up a little?

Answer (score 6):

When you blow into a solution, your warm breath (~98.6°F) warms the solution up. As a solution warms up, less $\ce{CO2}$ is soluble.  Therefore, blow into a solution, warm it up, less $\ce{CO2}$ is soluble, $\ce{CO2}$ escapes (bubbles out) from the warmer solution.

[image]

([image source](http://www.rocketscientistsjournal.com/2006/10/co2_acquittal.html))

Comment: Hmm I never considered this simple possibility. I thought the blown air was acting as a nucleation site for removal of the supersaturated $\ce{CO2}$ in solution. [Bubbles are good at nucleating other bubbles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61694/23152), which is why opening shaken cans of soda is not a good idea!

Comment: I don't believe this answer is fully correct. I repeated the experiment, this time using one of those dust-off air blower things, which blow out COLD air, and I got the same effect. In fact the more intense the spray, the more bubbles. So there's something more here.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because its incomplete. Increasing temperature of the solution can't be the only reason and when the temperature actually decreases it's not a reason at all. I think Nicolaw Saker Neto has the other half with bubbles nucleating other bubbles.

Comment: @ron But blowing a few air bubbles into a glass of Coke doesn't increase its temperature by anything even close to 10°C. Heat conduction between a gas bubble and a liquid is very slow and the bubble exists in the liquid for, what, about a second? I'd be surprised if blowing bubbles had any significant effect on temperature.

Comment: @DavidRicherby wrote "blowing a few air bubbles into a glass", the lungs contain around 6 liters of 98.6°F air.  Also, I just used 10° as an example, a 1° change could release significant $\ce{CO2}$

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou  What was the temperature of the air from the cold blower and what was the temperature of the drink?

Comment: @ron Nothing in the question talks about blowing a whole lungful of air through the drink.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou  How much air did you blow into the drink through the straw?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Nor does it say a few bubbles.  Just thinking back to when I was a kid and we'd blow a lot of air in.

Comment: The drink was at room temperature and the temperature of the air is less than that.

Comment: I think this is a very under-appreciated answer and I do not understand Joshua's reaction at all. It might not be complete, but it is far away from wrong. I am sorry about that. (In this case, if this was my answer, I would remove the answer, just because I could.)